# BeautifulSoup getting content of &lt; &gt; tags

Tags: beautifulsoup, meta-tags

I have a set of scraped pages that I have to use (can't scrape these again) that contain meta information in quoted `&lt; &gt;` tags like these:

```
 ...
 <span class="html-tag">
 &lt;meta <span class="html-attribute-name">name</span>="
 <span class="html-attribute-value">twitter:title</span>" 
 <span class="html-attribute-name">property</span>="
 <span class="html-attribute-value">og:title</span>" 
 <span class="html-attribute-name">content</span>="
 <span class="html-attribute-value">Smart TV wifi won't turn on</span>" /&gt;
 ...
 &lt;meta <span class="html-attribute-name">property</span>="
 <span class="html-attribute-value">og:url</span>" 
 <span class="html-attribute-name">content</span>="
 <span class="html-attribute-value">
 https://x.y.org/discussion/437/smart-tv-wifi-wont-turn-on</span>" /&gt;
 ...
```

**Update 3:**

These lines loaded in Chrome look like this:

```
  <meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" content="Smart TV wifi won't turn on" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://x.y.org/discussion/437/lg-smart-tv-wifi-wont-turn-on" />
```

**yet raw scraped text instead of `<meta>` tags has  `&lt;meta .... &gt;meta`**

**Is it possible to get content from `&lt;meta .... &gt;meta` tags with BeautifulSoup ?** Like in this case I need to get "Smart TV wifi won't turn on" and url "https://x.y.org/discussion/437/smart-tv-wifi-wont-turn-on"
How to do this?

Comment: i don't understand your target yet

Comment: I need to get "Smart TV wifi won't turn on" from html in my example

Comment: check below answer then

Comment: Thanks, but I have hundreds of different 'html-attribute-value' in my file

Comment: Please, see my question update

Comment: so you want to find the text of `span` which having `/&gt;` ?

Comment: I need to extract content from \&ltmeta .... &\gtmeta tags

Comment: Please see Update 2.

Comment: check below answer, and for any future questions, kindly please include all details from `1st` time to make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you want.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''
<span class="html-tag">
 &lt;meta <span class="html-attribute-name">name</span>="
 <span class="html-attribute-value">twitter:title</span>" 
 <span class="html-attribute-name">property</span>="
 <span class="html-attribute-value">og:title</span>" 
 <span class="html-attribute-name">content</span>="
 <span class="html-attribute-value">Smart TV wifi won't turn on</span>" /&gt;
 ...
 &lt;meta <span class="html-attribute-name">property</span>="
 <span class="html-attribute-value">og:url</span>" 
 <span class="html-attribute-name">content</span>="
 <span class="html-attribute-value">
 https://x.y.org/discussion/437/smart-tv-wifi-wont-turn-on</span>" /&gt;
'''

doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
block = doc.getSectionByReg('&lt;meta[\s\S]+?/&gt;') # Get the first data block. 
span = SimplifiedDoc(block).getElementByText('content').next.text
print (span)

blocks = doc.getSectionsByReg('&lt;meta[\s\S]+?/&gt;') # Get all data blocks
for block in blocks:
    span = SimplifiedDoc(block).getElementByText('content').next.text
    print (span)
```

Result:

```
Smart TV wifi won't turn on
Smart TV wifi won't turn on
https://x.y.org/discussion/437/smart-tv-wifi-wont-turn-on
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """ ...
 <span class="html-tag">
 &lt;meta <span class="html-attribute-name">name</span>="
 <span class="html-attribute-value">twitter:title</span>" 
 <span class="html-attribute-name">property</span>="
 <span class="html-attribute-value">og:title</span>" 
 <span class="html-attribute-name">content</span>="
 <span class="html-attribute-value">Smart TV wifi won't turn on</span>" /&gt;
 ...
 """


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("span", {'class': 'html-attribute-value'})[2]:
    print(item)
```

Update:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """<meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" content="Smart TV wifi won't turn on" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://x.y.org/discussion/437/lg-smart-tv-wifi-wont-turn-on" />"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("meta", property=re.compile("^og")):
    print(item.get("content"))
```

Output:

```
Smart TV wifi won't turn on
https://x.y.org/discussion/437/lg-smart-tv-wifi-wont-turn-on
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have hundreds of different 'html-attribute-value' in my file

Comment: i didn't get your question at all. did you run the code and checked the output ?

Comment: Thanks, but this dose not work for my file. Please note: Instead of <meta > tags I have \&ltmeta .... &\gtmeta, so your code returns empty results. Again, I have no <meta> tags! It is just Chrome that shows it with <meta>, but scraped file has \&ltmeta .... &\gtmeta instead.

Comment: @dokondr share your file content then